# Returning from inside the scope of a 'using' statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
using (DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext(ConnectionString))
{
    Main main = new Main
    {
        ClientTime = clientTime
    };
    dc.Mains.InsertOnSubmit(main);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
    return main.ID;
}
```

If I return from inside a "using", will the using still clean up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, and that's one of the big advantages of `using` it.

Comment: tempted to -1 for the pun, but +1 all the same ;)

Answer (score 12):

Yes. It really is just the equivalent of a `try/finally` statement - and `finally` blocks get executed however the `try` block exits, whether through an exception, a return statement, or just getting to the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all object instances that were initialized in the resource-acquisition part of the using statement will have their `Dispose()` method called automatically.

Comment: Only those objects which are specified within the resource-acquisition part of the using statement are disposed, and *nothing* special happens in terms of garbage collection.

Comment: @Jon, thanks.. I wasn't specific enough.. thus making my answer incorrect.  Will fix.

Comment: @fallen888 - I changed it to reflect what Jon was saying, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will clean up.  I see this as C#'s poor ass attempt to support the [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern.

Comment: RAII is unique to C++, because it is inherently based on C++'s unique stack-object construction/destruction features. C# borrowed the pattern from C++ because it proved useful, but had to modify the pattern, because stack-object construction/destruction does not work the same way as it does in C++.

Comment: @Justice - that's a long winded, but far more useful, version of "poor ass attempt".